# Framemaker to LaTeX

Tags: html, pandoc, xml

I'm a software person who has been tasked with moving a few thousand pages of documentation for a piece of legacy software online.  The documentation is all in Adobe Framemaker and yes, there are lots of equations.  The Framemaker HTML output is ugly and I'm thinking that moving everything to LaTeX would be painful but worth the effort because a) I and other people know it, b) it looks good, and c) it's flexible.

Please weigh in on:

Is this plan crazy?  I'm not a technical writer and I don't want to misjudge the magnitude of this.

Are there any Framemaker conversion tools out there?  Right now I'm thinking of saving the .fm docs in HTML and using Pandoc to convert to LaTeX.  Does anyone have experience with any part of this?

Any advice about the equations?

Comment: I would suggest something like [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/), maybe.

Comment: The more 'structured' the HTML output is, the easier the task will be.  But a few thousand pages? Are you going to read it all? If so, you'll be reading a few thousand pages at least twice.  That's a lot of pretty unexciting (I'd guess) reading.

Comment: Did a bit of web surfing.  I have never used FrameMaker but his may have potential.http://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptexternal/wiki/Main/FramemakerToLaTeX   And here is another link http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/framemaker/.  And http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/framemaker/mif_la.html   I would recommend you test any solution with a small representative subset of the documentation (10-20 pages)

Comment: "The Framemaker HTML output is ugly", Is HTML output from LaTeX code not ugly? Did you test that. I always found HTML conversion tools from LaTeX pretty poor. Maybe because the target format/structure is quite different. Maybe the situation has improved lately.

Comment: Are you talking about ugly _HTML_ or about an ugly-looking output? Even the prettiest HTML looks bad without a proper CSS (stylesheet).

Comment: For the record, I ended up using the same WebWorks tool we use to generate our chm help for the html output.  It's okay.  My feeling is that if I got to the point of working directly with the CSS I would become our full-time documentation person, which I definitely don't want. :)

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, LaTeX doesn't have good support for tagged PDFs. If that is required, you might have to do some more research.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this plan crazy?

Do I get you right: You are interested in quite some hundreds pages filled with equations?

If so, will they have been converted into images, when Framemaker produced its HTML? If so, can they be reused or is their quality poor? Can you please elaborate on the "uglyness"? Do you mean the presentation within several browsers, the files produced or sth. else, e.g. like html produced by Word?

> I'm not a technical writer and I don't want to misjudge the magnitude
> of this.

This might be worth a closer consideration. Is there some kind of document management or house style for documents in place? If so, talking to those people responsible would certainly be good. If they have guidlines for web-content, you should know and follow them. Else you might be free to decide.

> everything to LaTeX

Assume, you made it. What are the next steps after that?